# Derivation of Binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Let $F(x)$ be the function defined by (1):

$$ 1)F(x)=(1-e^{-ax})^N$$
Using the binomial theorem $F(x)$ can be written as (2):
cc\begin{equation}
2)F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N}{n}(-1)^ne^{-axn}
\end{equation}

Now the Derivation of $F(x)$ is $f(x)=F'(x)$
$$ 3) f(x)=aNe^{-ax}(1-e^{-ax})^{N-1}$$
Similar using binomial theorem 
$$ 4)f(x)=aN\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{n}(-1)^ne^{-ax(n+1)}$$

My question how we derive (2) to get (4)?

Comment: The derivative of a finite sum is just the sum of the derivative.

Comment: How please can i get

Comment: $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x)\right)'=\sum_{k=0}^n f_k'(x).$$ difficult to be more clear...

Comment: Can we try fo example $N=3$

Comment: SO we can never go from (2) to (4)

Comment: The verb for the process of forming a derivative is "differentiate", whereas "derive" means "deduce".

Comment: @Surb: I think that's not what the OP intended to ask about. The question is about how to show the equality of the two sums, not about the general rule of differentiating a sum by differentiating the terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N} \binom{N}{n} (-1)^n e^{-axn}\right)' = \sum_{n=1}^{N} an\binom{N}{n} (-1)^{n+1} e^{-axn}$$
then we use the fact $$k \binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} an\binom{N}{n} (-1)^{n+1} e^{-axn} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} aN\binom{N-1}{n-1} (-1)^{n+1} e^{-axn} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}aN\binom{N-1}{n}(-1)^{n}e^{-ax(n+1)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much , but which proprieties you have use here $$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} aN\binom{N-1}{n-1} (-1)^{n+1} e^{axn} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}aN\binom{N-1}{n}(-1)^{n}e^{ax(n+1)}$$

Comment: @BouMokhtar I've just changed the index of summation

Comment: ok so for $n=0$ we have remove this term , what about the proprtie that you have used?

Comment: @BouMokhtar try $j = n-1 \to n = j+1 \to \sum_{n = 1}^N = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1}$ and etc

Answer (score 1):

> **Hint:** After derivation use the binomial identity $\binom{N}{n}=\frac{N}{n}\binom{N-1}{n-1}$ and then apply an index shift.

Comment: Could please show me because my knowledge  in binomial theorem and coefficient is very  poor

Comment: \begin{align}
f(x)&=(\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N}{n}(-1)^ne^{-axn})^{'}\\
f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N}{n}(-1)^{n+1}ane^{-ax(n-1)}\\ 
\end{align} using $$\binom{N}{n}=\frac{N}{n}\binom{N-1}{n-1}$$                                                  \begin{align}
f(x)&=aN\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N-1}{n-1}(-1)^{n+1}e^{-ax(n-1)}\\
\end{align}  How can I continue ?

Comment: @BouMokhtar: Use simply the definition of $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Ok thanks for every one helping me.

Comment: @BouMokhtar: You're welcome.